# How do you show and hide the grid? Viewport overlays dimmed out

Tags: 3d-view

I imagine if I close and reopen blender it fix it.. But I'm curious to what I might have done.

[image: Can't bring back up the grid lines...]

Comment: you just disabled the overlay by clicking on the "2 spheres" icon (it's blue when enabled)

Comment: You're right thanks man!